# Justify and Bold text in SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: html, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

As SSRS not providing a built-in Text Justify option, I have used the following VB code to fulfill my requirement.

```
Function GetText(text As String, width As Integer) As String
        Dim palabras As String() = text.Split(" "c)  'text-->palabras
        Dim sb1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim sb2 As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim length As Integer = palabras.Length     'palabras
        Dim resultado As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < length
            sb1.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras(i))   'palabras
            If sb1.ToString().Length > width Then
                resultado.Add(sb2.ToString())
                sb1 = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                sb2 = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(i), i + 1)
            Else
                sb2.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras(i))
            End If
            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
        End While
        resultado.Add(sb2.ToString())               'resultado

        Dim resultado2 As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)()
        Dim temp As String

        Dim index1 As Integer, index2 As Integer, salto As Integer
        Dim target As String
        Dim limite As Integer = resultado.Count     'resultado
        For Each item As String In resultado        'resultado
            target = " "
            temp = item.ToString().Trim()
            index1 = 0
            index2 = 0
            salto = 2

            If limite <= 1 Then
                resultado2.Add(temp)
                Exit For
            End If
            While temp.Length <= width
                If temp.IndexOf(target, index2) < 0 Then
                    index1 = 0
                    index2 = 0
                    target = target + " "
                    System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(salto), salto - 1)
                End If
                index1 = temp.IndexOf(target, index2)
                temp = temp.Insert(temp.IndexOf(target, index2), " ")

                index2 = index1 + salto
            End While
            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(limite), limite + 1)
            resultado2.Add(temp)
        Next

        Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each item As String In resultado2
            builder.Append(item).Append(chr(10))
       Next
        Return builder.ToString()
    End Function
```

The code is working fine and the only drawback is, that I have to use a monospaced font in the report.

My issue is that, I need to bold some parts of the paragraphs that I am justifying using the above code, and to fulfil this, the only solution I found is using the HTML `<b>` tag around the required text. To work the HTML tags, I have to change the expression's markup type as HTML. After changing this, the bold is working fine, but the Justify is not working properly.

Any possibilities to fulfill both requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your text is HTML markup then you need to use that to justify the text, which means using a CSS style. You can find out how to align text in HTML using CSS with a web search.

Comment: Don't modern browsers support styles now? Have you tried `div { text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word; }`?

Comment: ="<div text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;> Some Text </div>" 
                 
="<div style='text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;'> Some Text </div>"
Tried above both. But not working.

Comment: [It looks like there's not a lot of support for `text-justify` outside of Firefox.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify#browser_compatibility)

Comment: SSRS is a server product that hosts reports created in Report Builder or Visual Studio. Which tool are you using to create the reports?

Comment: I'm using Report Builder.